# Quem quaeritis?

Tags: medieval-latin, grammar-identification

Different versions of the [*Visitatio sepulchri*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quem_quaeritis%3F), have different line endings. Some use **Christicole** whereas elsewhere I have seen **Christicolae**.

What is the difference between Christicole/Christicoles/Christicolae and which is correct?!

Answer (score 8):

["-cola"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-cola) is a productive suffix that can be used for the pretty wide array of meanings of [*colo, -ere*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcolo1):

1. inhabit (caeli-cola: inhabitant of heaven)
2. cultivate (agri-cola: cultivator of fields = farmer)
3. worship (Iunoni-cola: worshipper of Juno)

In this case, the third meaning is intended, so we get [*Christicola, -ae*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3DChristicola), a "worshipper of Christ," i.e. a Christian. This is a masculine first declension noun like "agricola."

In the *Visitatio Sepulchri*, the relevant line is a question ending with a **vocative plural**:

> *Quem quaeritis in sepulchro, o Christicolae?*

> Whom do you seek in the tomb, O worshippers of Christ?

In Medieval Latin, *e* was interchangeable with *ae* and *oe*, and was almost always used instead. So, the above line could also read:

> Quem qu***e***ritis in sepulcro, o Christicol***e***?

This is a difference of spelling/orthography, not of case. You will almost certainly find that any text that spells "Christicolae" with an "e" will also spell the prior "quaeritis" with an "e."

As for the other variant you mention (*Christicoles*), I've been unable to find an example, and I would be surprised if that actually occurred.

Comment: I wonder if *Christocoles* is a borrowing in English, like *Christians* is for *Christiani*.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer Good point. I forgot to mention that "Christicoles" *does* return quite a few French results.

Answer (score 8):

**Christicole** is a medieval misspelling, reflecting the way vernacular pronunciation had changed in some parts of Europe. **Christicolae** is the corrected spelling.

In classical pronunciation, **ae** was a diphthong, pronounced like English long **ī**. During the Middle Ages, in much of Europe, the **ae** phoneme altered and became identical to **e**, pronounced like English long **ā** (but not a diphthong, i.e. without a *-y* sound at the end).

Latin is defined by its writing, not by its pronunciation. Each country has its own pronunciation, which is basically to pronounce Latin as if it were the vernacular language, i.e. using the same sounds. Latin spelling should remain the same in all countries, but in the Middle Ages, scribes often wrote **e** instead of **ae** because in the spoken Latin they heard all around them, **ae** was pronounced **e**. In the Renaissance, the medieval spellings were corrected, but of course they persist to the present day in many manuscripts.

You can see this and a little more by comparing these two versions of the *Quem quaeritis*:

Classical spelling (from [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41917126%5D)):*

> Quem quaeritis in sepulchro, o Christicolae?
> Ihesum Nazarenum crucifixum, o caelicolae.
> Non est hic, surrexit sicut praedixerat; ite, nuntiate quia surrexit de sepulchro.

Medieval spelling (from [here](https://www.oxfordmusiconline.com/grovemusic/view/10.1093/gmo/9781561592630.001.0001/omo-9781561592630-e-0000022681)):

> Quem queritis in sepulcro, o Christicole?
> Ihesum Nazarenum crucifixum, o celicole.
> Non est hic, surrexit sicut ipse dixit; ite, nunciate quia surrexit.

Notice that every **ae** was changed to **e**. Also, **nuntiate** became **nunciate**, reflecting changes in pronunciation that still can be seen in the Italian word [*annunciate*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/annunciate#Italian), the French word [*annoncez*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/annoncez#French), and even the English word [*announce*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/announce).

**Christicolae** is the plural of **Christicola** (Christ-worshiper). **Caelicola** (heaven-dweller) likewise has the plural **caelicolae**—and likewise the [regional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_regional_pronunciation) medieval variant has singular **celicola** and plural **celicole**. This change in the plural can still be seen in many feminine nouns in Italian today. For example, where Latin has singular *vita* (life) and plural *vitae*, Italian has *vita* and *vite*.

The differences in entire words between the two versions, like **praedixerat** (he had foretold) vs. **ipse dixit** (he himself said) are just differences in versions, not medieval strayings from classical standards.

**Christicoles** sounds to me like a different kind of error: a mistranscription rather than changes in regional vernacular pronunciations influencing spelling.

---

* Translation:

> Whom do you seek in the tomb, O Christ-worshipers?
> The crucified Nazarene Jesus, O heaven-dwellers.
> He is not here, he has risen just as he foretold; go, announce that he has risen from the tomb.

Comment: Excellent answer (+1). Perhaps I'm overly sensitive, but I'm hesitant to call this a "misspelling." The idea of "correct spelling" is a rather modern idea, and I wouldn't want to say that Plautus (for example) "spells badly." It just reflects a different spoken convention.

Comment: @brianpck I'm going with "correct spelling" on the principle that since classical Latin became standardized, it has culturally served as a prescriptive standard in relation to which the medieval variances are seen as corruptions, which, for example, writers in the Renaissance sought to undo. I know that contemporary linguists dismiss all "prescriptivism", but I think they're ignoring something important about language. More in [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/53560/6700).

Comment: Thank you for these answers. I believe my source referring to 'worshippers' as 'Christicola' is valid, as it is in all likelihood taken from the medieval.

Comment: @Johnny Note that _Christicola_ is singular (Christ-worshipper). The plural is _Christicolae_ (classical spelling) or _Christicole_ (medieval spelling often used in some regions, where the phonetic distinction between _ae_ and _e_ had been lost in vernacular speech). I'll add a sentence or two to the answer about _caelicola_ and its plural, in which you can see the same medieval straying from classical standards.

Comment: @BenKovitz I'm not unsympathetic to prescriptivism, but I was just (mildly) objecting to the note of censure or ignorance that "misspelling" implies. If you've ever taken a look at medieval paleography (such as [this 13th c. autograph](https://digi.vatlib.it/view/MSS_Vat.lat.9851) by Tommy Aqua), "misspelling" is either unfair or the understatement of the century.

Comment: @brianpck I certainly wouldn't want to disparage medieval sigla! Let's hope that the background, in my answer and in yours, guides the reader to understand that plural *-e* is not a mere typo, nor a true solecism like "should of" in English, but a common medieval practice that strayed, due to vernacular influence, from the standard held as authoritative for the formal language—and, I believe, was regarded by many scholars as somewhat ignorant, meriting correction for this reason. Maybe we need a question about degrees of censure-worthiness in medieval variances from classical precedents.

Comment: Chalk this up to my own ignorance, but at what point did scholars consider it incorrect? Is there a continuation of Medieval scholars who objected to the -e spelling?